# how to add column values in multiple csv files at once

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, tuples

I have this code snippet and want to add some extra column values in the multiple CSV files

```
   header = ['Name','Final_marks', 'Practical_marks','extra_marks','date']
```

I need a random value between 10 to 20 in the "extra_marks" column in all the CSV file.
and in the date section, I need current data only. in this format = 20210320

In this code, I have values for only the first 3 columns and another two-column I need to fill specific values for all the rows.

```
 import csv
 data_dict = {"Jhon":[(75,25),(34,20),(33,88),(44,90),(43,99)],"Ram":[(10,11),(90,90),(11,34),(9,12),(-43,-99),(1,2)]}

 header = ['Name','Final_marks', 'Practical_marks','extra_marks','date']
 file_name = 'zoutput_csv_file_'
 file_number, rows_per_file = 1, 10

 def fetch(data):
    for key,values in data.items():
        for value in values:
            yield (key,) + value   # e.g. ('John', 75, 25)

gen = fetch(data_dict)  # create a generator over all the data

for row in gen:         # fetch a row, if one isn't available, stop

# Since at least one row is available, start a new file.
# Ensuring one row is available prevents a header-only file
# when there is an exact multiple of rows_per_file data rows.
# Open file, write the header and first row
    with open(f'{file_name}{file_number}.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
        writer = csv.writer(fp)
        writer.writerow(header)
        writer.writerow(row)

        try:  # try to write up to the max rows per file, but stop if you run out
            for i in range(rows_per_file - 1):
                writer.writerow(next(gen))
        except StopIteration:
            break

        file_number += 1
```

Comment: So, what's preventing you from doing what you want to do?

Comment: values for other column are not generated

Comment: Try: `yield (key, value, random.randint(10, 20), datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d"))`, don't forget to `import random; from datetime import datetime`